# How can I remove duplicate attributes in a HTML File?

Tags: html, html-parsing

I need to remove/ignore duplicate attributes in the HTML. I use xerces2 html parser. It does not parse HTML files with duplicate attributes in tags.

Example:

```
<img src="url" width="100" height="200" width="123">
```

Comment: Why put duplicates attributes in the first place ?

Comment: serverside or clientside?

Comment: jQuery may be able to do that ?

Comment: Duplicate attributes are already present in the content.

Answer (score 0):

you can try cyber neko html parser ,to parse your html file.
http://sourceforge.net/projects/nekohtml/